# Using django-admin in Atom Powershell

Tags: python, django, atom-editor

I am trying for hours but can not get rid of these django error. I have also added the path variable.

PS E:\atom\python> django-admin startproject mysite
django-admin : The term 'django-admin' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- django-admin startproject mysite
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (django-admin:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Does it work if you don't use atom? Maybe a stupid question but if it doesn't work outside atom then it would seem its a system issue rather than an atom one is all

Comment: i fixed it. worked in atom.

Comment: Maybe it is worth writing the answer to your own question to help others with a similar question in the future :) glad you fixed it!

Comment: Sorry I forgot to answer earlier. I just missed a line of code their a hyphen or something as much as I can recall. so guys be aware about your syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, you can use python -m flag, to run library modules as script.

> -m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)

Basically, the above flag will help you summon all library modules from the terminal.

In specific to your use-case:

```
python -m django startproject <app_name>
```

Here we use python -m flag to summon django module, then we startproject feature to create a site.

In a similar way you can call many python libraries with this method, and to understand the features in those method, you can use:

```
python -m <module_name>
```

It will list you the available modules which you can try.